# nvprof on a binary file

Tags: cuda, profile

I have a binary of my program which is generated with nvcc compiler. I want to profile it with nvprof. I tried with `nvprof ./a.out` and it shows seconds for each function. While this is good for me, I want to see timeline of my application. I could have easily done this thing, if I was building my project with Nsight but unfortunately I can't do that. So, how can I invoke nvprof program outside Nsight in order to see timeline of my application?

Comment: You can do `nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./a.out` to get the timeline.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways that you can see the timeline:

1. In Nsight, click the profile button after compiling;
2. Use standalone GUI profile tool nvvp in CUDA, which can be launched by the following cmdline if `/usr/local/cuda/bin` (default CUDA installation binary dir) is in your `$PATH`. You can then lanuch your `a.out` in nvvp GUI to profile it and display the timeline.

   ```
   $ nvvp
   ```
3. Use cmdline tool `nvprof` with `-o` option to generate the result file, which can be imported by Nsight and/or nvvp to display the timeline. the [user manual of nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) provides more details.

   ```
   $ nvprof -o profile.result ./a.out
   ```